# How to save the QGIS SCRIPT result in a folder

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2.14

I would like to save my result from QGIS Script in a folder but I don't know how.

```
##Input_raster=raster
##result_out=output raster

outputs_SAGARASTERCALCULATOR_1=processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator', Input_raster,[],'ifelse(gt(a,-1),1,0)',False,7,result_out)
```

I would like to save the results in a folder that I can easily change.

I am using QGIS 2.14.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, what version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: add code in your question,so we can help you.

Comment: It's really hard to answer this question in it's current state. Please add some context, write what you have already tried and research you have done so far.

Comment: Do you want to hardcode the folder path in your script? Otherwise, when you run the script, there is a button with three dots next to the output box which lets you choose where you want to save the output. And you need to remove the extra space in `##result_out =output raster` so that it reads `##result_out=output raster` :)

Comment: i am using QGIS 2.14. ##artwork21

Comment: Joseph I would like to save in hard results in a folder that I can easily change

Comment: @Dokpe - To notify others, use the @ symbol followed by their name. Your question is being flagged because there's not enough information in your question. But you mentioned some in your comments, could you please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/206305/edit) your question to include what you wrote in the comments?

Comment: @Dokpe - Most welcome and don't worry, you will get used to the site mechanics quickly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should work where you specify the folder you want the output to be saved:

```
##Input_raster=raster
##result_out=folder

result = result_out + "/result.tif"
processing.runalg('saga:rastercalculator', Input_raster,[],'ifelse(gt(a,-1),1,0)',False,7,result)
```

Comment: Why not directly `##result_file=file`? This way you spare some lines..

Comment: @matteo - Yup, your method works just as well =). I just included the `folder` parameter as that was what the OP seemed to be asking for.

Comment: @Dokpe - Most welcome, glad it helped :)